# Convert HEX string into multiple decimals SQL Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Given the HEX string below which contains of 3 different values: 32bit, 32bit, 16bit, I need to split it into 3 different decimals.
For example:
0x40,0xb,0x0,0x0,0x2,0x9,0x0,0x0,0x2a,0x0

0x40,0xb,0x0,0x0  ==> 0xb40 ==> **2880**

0x2,0x9,0x0,0x0   ==> 0X902 ==> **2306**

0x2a,0x0          ==> 0x2a  ==> **42**

with hex as (
select '0x40,0xb,0x0,0x0,0x2,0x9,0x0,0x0,0x2a,0x0' hex_col
)

How do I convert it in SQL (BQ)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are some standard HEX functions -- see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#from_hex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Here it is:

```
with hex as (
  select '0x40,0xb,0x0,0x0,0x2,0x9,0x0,0x0,0x2a,0x0' hex_col
)    
select 
  hex_col, val_0, val_1, val_2
from (
  select hex_col, div(offset, 4) grp, cast('0x' || string_agg(lpad(replace(sh, '0x', ''),2,'0'),'' order by mod(offset, 4) desc) as int64) val
  from hex, unnest(split(hex_col)) sh with offset
  group by hex_col, grp
)
pivot (any_value(val) as val for grp in (0, 1, 2))
```